# Why did Puzzle Rush stop at the second fail?

Tags: online-chess, puzzles

I was playing the popular Puzzle Rush game on chess.com (3-minute version), and the game stopped when I missed the second puzzle (I had 8 seconds left on the clock). The statement is "Three strikes and you are out!", and it usually complies.

I must clarify that **this is not the updated version of Puzzle Rush**, which started at 9 a.m. Pacific time on [Thursday, November 21](https://www.chess.com/news/view/new-puzzle-rush-chess).

[image: Puzzle Rush stopped]

It's the second time I’ve seen this happen.
I am wondering if there is a special rule that I have missed, or if it is just a bug.

Comment: No, you are probably talking about Puzzle Battle. This is a one-player game.

Comment: You can also take too long on one individual puzzle, and get stopped that way. That might be it, but without having seen you play at the time, I cannot be sure that is what happened to you. If it is, please report back, and I will post this as an actual answer.

Comment: Thank you @PhishMaster, that is interesting, but I don't really remember that. Do you have a source for that rule in Puzzle Rush?

Comment: I do not know about the rules. I am just talking from experience. I have played, and pretty sure that I have run out of time on an individual problem....then again, I am older now, and I might just be remembering it wrong. :)

Comment: @DanielAlfredoSottile I think it is the network lag to blame. I have experienced serious lag while playing puzzle rush. I don't think this lag is considered in time limit.

Comment: Good hypothesis, thanks. But I don't think so, my side of the network is pretty stable and fast, 8 seconds seem too much... but maybe.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'quit' flag on the webpage of puzzle rush, so perhaps you could have accidentally clicked it.

Answer (score -2):

The web version as implemented by chess.com is laggy and your clock runs down without you knowing when the browser is loading and the timer is suffering severe latency problems.

I created the original Prototype A of this puzzle app style and it was lag proof but chess.com copied it and didn’t know how to avoid this issue.